# Angular 5 Service worker not working / Doesn't cache background-image

Tags: angular, background-image, browser-cache, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I'm having trouble getting my angular5 service worker to work. I have two main problems:

1. The service worker doesn't cache assets images that are used as background-images
2. After simulating a network disconnect the service worker initially pulls files from the cache (except the the aforementioned non cached files), but after a second refresh it runs into an error.

Below is a more detailed report of my problem. You can follow along by cloning a repo I made to highlight this problem located [here.](https://github.com/osa10928/test-angular5-serviceWorker)

I created the application with the --service-worker tag provided. I then ensured that the 5 steps listed on the Angular documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started) were followed, namely:

1. Service worker package is added.
2. angular-cli.json has service-worker set to true
3. Service worker is imported and registered in app.module.ts
4. ngsw-config.json was generated and configured as described in the documentation.
5. Run ng build --prod to generate bundles in my dist folder of the application.

I serve my application using node/express and a server.js document. When I open the application in an incognito window (as recommended by the documentation) I see my service worker gets registered and a cache stores my bundles and index file. It also caches the image that is used in an img tag, but it does not cache the images specified in my css background-image. When I simulate a network problem by checking the offline box on my service worker and then refresh my page, the page displays everything correctly except the parts that require background images.

But the final/main problem occurs when I refresh the application a second time or open another tab (on the same incognito window so the service worker is still registered and cache is still active). At this point I get nothing displayed. The console gives me three error:

1. GET http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
2. An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.
3. Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

with the last error coming from ngsw-worker.js. I'm not quite sure what to make of these error. I think maybe a new service worker is trying to be registered but I'm not sure why that would happen...

here is my ng-config.json file as requested:

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [{
    "name": "app",
    "installMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/favicon.ico",
        "/index.html"
      ],
      "versionedFiles": [
        "/*.bundle.css",
        "/*.bundle.js",
        "/*.chunk.js"
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "name": "assets",
    "installMode": "lazy",
    "updateMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/assets/**"
      ]
    }
  }]
}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks all

**Update**

So I've noticed that when I go to localhost:3000 without the server running I get the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Response not Ok (fetchAndCacheOnce): request for http://localhost:3000/assets/images/background-silver-grainy.jpg returned response 504 Gateway Timeout
```

I also get the errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 (Gateway Timeout)
```

Comming from all my resources

**Update2**

I've been testing this project using node to serve an express application that directs all requests to my angular application located in a dist folder (which is generated after running ng build --prod). I decided to test it on a simple http-server. I also found that doing a direct reload breaks my service worker, but if I navigate to another page, then back to my original page, the service worker works (weird but unrelated to this question).

I still can't get the service worker to work with express though...

Comment: can you share your ngsw-config.json

Comment: Coming right up!

Comment: what do you use to serve your app ?

Comment: node running an express server. You can see those files at the github for this test repo using the first 'here' hyperlink in the post.

Comment: Do you run two servers ? one for API and one for UI ? what's node running an express server used for?

Comment: I only run one server. The node server serves and express application by running . The express application directs all requests to my application (Which lies in dist folder produced by running `ng build --prod`).

Comment: I'm having similar issues with an Angular-App created with Angular CLI 1.6.3. When going offline the page loads right one or two times. But after some time/reloads I'm also getting HTTP 504 Errors.

Comment: I’m pretty much having this same issue.   Spent all day on it :( and no resolution.  Any resolutions ?  I’ll go watch some pbs spacetime I guess.   After a bunch of physics I feel smarter and can sometimes make progress when I otherwise wouldn’t have

Comment: Well I realized some things about the worker. 1. in development I think the localhost server has to be running for the service worker to recieve the request. I think this because in docs, the never say to stop running the server except to make changes, but they always say to turn the server back on before examining the service worker (even when they have you check the offline button). 2. My service worker doesn't always work on a direct refresh, but it usually works when I navigate to another page then come back. Its annoying and I'm still looking into it, but I have other things to accomplish

Comment: @StephenAgwu .  #2 is what i'm experiencing.. and yes.. it's annoying

Comment: This just happened to me. Fixed it by opening dev tools in Chrome and right clicking the refresh icon to clear cache and hard reload. It seems there is some cache bug with a new update to your app in Service Workers, but not sure exactly what it is. This solution is working.

Answer (score 6):

*First, Service Worker works only on --prod builds.

*Secondly, Service Worker can't be served over `ng serve`, after you make your
`ng build --prod` you need to serve your app using a different server like:

1- `npm install -g http-server`// install http-server globally
2- cd dist
3- http-server -p 4200
4- open your browser on localhost:4200

*Thirdly, and most importantly, you have to enable cache in your browser, uncheck "Disable Cache" in your dev tool if you have it checked.

This is your app served and everything loads from service worker offline

[image]

Comment: sorry if I didn't make it clear but I have done everything you suggest. My step 5 says I build a dist folder using ng build --prod. The very next sentence I say that I serve application with node using an express file server.js

Comment: @stephenagwu do you have cache enabled ?

Comment: Yes I do. But I just noticed another error that they are giving me... I'll update the post

Comment: @stephenagwu Also using  incognito window doesn't save your cache

Comment: It doesn't save a cache after you close the window but it does save it while you have a session

Comment: The documentation actually recommends you develop in incognito mode. [Tip: When testing Angular service workers, it's a good idea to use an incognito or private window in your browser to ensure the service worker doesn't end up reading from a previous leftover state, which can cause unexpected behavior.](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started)

Comment: The reason I'm serving from node using express is that I'm trying to create a mean stack... That being said I tried your method of using an http-server. I did get the worker to serve all the img files that way initially. But if I reload the page the service worker breaks (or at leasts stops serving files). Does this happen to you?

Comment: @stephenagwu no, you can see in the image attached that I was able to get your repo to load fine with no issues at all. first load it, refresh, go offline, refresh again and everything works

Comment: I've found that if I navigate to another page, then back to the page I'm testing on the service worker works fine. Its only if I do a direct reload that the service worker breaks (weird but tolerable and unrelated to this question). Now I just got to get it to work with my MEAN stack. Thanks for all the help

Comment: @StephenAgwu can you please share a plunker for the same?