# Angular 5 service worker not working with Express

Tags: node.js, angular, express, service-worker, angular-service-worker

So for like 2 days I've been having some trouble with my Angular5 service worker, but I think I've narrowed it down to it being the way I serve the application. You can read in detail how I came to this point at [from this SO question I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48569933/angular-5-service-worker-not-working-doesnt-cache-background-image/48572505?noredirect=1#comment84168351_48572505) or you can read the summary:

The service worker works when running my app from an `http-server`, but not when I use node to serve my express application.

The main problem I see right now is that when I serve my application with `node/express` application the Network tab in my dev tools gives me a `504` status for `localhost:3000` when my network is offline. Its as if the service worker is not pointing to `localhost:3000/index.html`. But this is not a problem when serving the file the http-server.

Here is my `server.js` file which I have node use to serve my angular application:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const logger = require('morgan');
const app = express();
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const bluebird = require('bluebird')


// Parsers
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(logger('dev'));

// Angular DIST output folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));


// Send all other requests to the Angular app
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'dist/index.html'));
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 var err = new Error('Not Found');
 err.status = 404;
 next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
 // set locals, only providing error in development
 res.locals.message = err.message;
 res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

 // render the error page
 res.status(err.status || 500);
 res.render('error');
});


// Set export
const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Running on localhost ${port}`));
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

**Extra Info**

1. I initiated my angular app with the tag --service-worker as describes byt the [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started) with no extra customization.
2. There is not console error. The only error is the 504 status in the network tab.
3. In both situations, a service worker is installed and all files that are supposed to be cached are cached.

If you want to test it out for yourself:
1. Download this test repo [here](https://github.com/osa10928/test-angular5-serviceWorker).
2. Run `npm install`. Then run `ng build --prod`.
3. To test the http-server run npm install http-server. Navigate to the dist folder and run `http-server -p 4200`.
4. To test the express server navigate to the root directory and run `node server.js`

**UPDATE**

(Sorry for my absense, I had real work to take care of, but I'm ready to attack the problem with fresh ideas)

I've noticed that if I similate the server being offline by checking the offline button on my dev-tools, that the console running my server still get requests. But when I check in the network toolbar in the devtools it says these requests are being served by the service worker. These request attempt to serve my background files but this fails with a 504 not found errors, only the index.html file and the picture thats in the element file is fetched. Also these request only work after navigating to a different page, never after a refresh.

If I turn the server off in the terminal, the service worker only attempts to get `localhost:3000` from the service worker but this fails with a 504 error. Nothing else is displayed on the screen and the network tab makes no other request except for an updated service worker file.

I don't quite no what to make of these findings and once again would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Quick guess, but try to `console.log(path.join(__dirname,'dist/index.html'))`.

I believe you'll get `/your/project/dirdist/index.html`. You're missing a `/`

Try :

```
path.join(__dirname,'/dist/index.html')
```

so you'll get :

`/your/project/dir/dist/index.html`

Comment: It's not true, path.join() will output the correct path even if you miss the trailing `/`, docs [here](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths)

Comment: Man I'm at a loss here: where do I place the console log??

Comment: Anywhere. You're logging a constant, so the output will be the same wherever you put this line. The point is to check whether your path is correct.

Comment: Sorry I've been gone for awhile. Had work to do during the week. Aywho, I placed the console.log but @YouneL is correct the leading `/` does not affect the pathname. I am getting the correct path name of `/your/project/dir/dist/index.html`. I do have an update/clarification I am about to post, please take a look!

Comment: Sorry I just saw your update, but I have no clue how to solve it :/